# Reading from Excel getting prompts instead of string on occasion

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

The issue i am having right now is that the first row of the data i get from the excel documents sometimes come back as prompts instead of their proper data types(only some of the cells). i have tried remaking the spreadsheets and redoing all the formatting on the excel side so i'm left to assume its something to do with the oledb class? Any information or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop


Public Class Form1
    Dim ExTable1 As New DataTable
    Dim ExTable2 As New DataTable

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        ExTable1 = ConnectToFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Table1.DataSource = ExTable1
    End Sub

    Function ConnectToFile(path)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim selStr As String = "SELECT * FROM [{0}]"
        Dim dtSchema
        Dim drSchema
        Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"

        con.Open()
        dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

        drSchema = dtSchema.Rows(0)
        Dim Sheet1 = drSchema("TABLE_NAME")
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(String.Format(selStr, Sheet1))

        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)
        Table1.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Do the spreadsheets have headers? `HDR=YES;` What is the Xml at the end of your connection string? There is quite a bit about Excel provider at https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prompts"?

Comment: prompts were the data type, that i was getting back. and the i messed with all the options on the connection string, managed to get something that kinda works but i ended up scarpping the idea and just coping the data over manually for now